# validating html color codes JS

Tags: javascript

i am looking for code to validate html color codes. wanna check if user typed valid color code, can you guyz help ?

i know i need that regex stuff but i cant understand a think about that regex things :S

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can match hexadecimal colors like this:

```
if (/^#[0-9a-f]{3}([0-9a-f]{3})?$/i.test(str)) {
    //Match
}
```

Note that this wont handle names or `rgb(n, n, n)`.

You can match `rgb(x, y, z)` colors like this:

```
if (/^rgb\s*(\s*[012]?[0-9]{1,2}\s*,\s*[012]?[0-9]{1,2}\s*,\s*[012]?[0-9]{1,2}\s*)$/i.test(str)) {
    //Match
}
```

Note that this will match `rgb(299, 299, 299)`.

Comment: It will handle #aaa which, while being a perfectly good CSS colour code is (like rgb()) not a valid HTML colour code.

Comment: ?? 3-digit color codes are definitely valid.  They mean the same as 6-digit codes, where the second digit of each color part is "0".

Comment: Note: you need to have a (?:) grouping around that second block (turning the string into `if (/^#[0-9a-f]{3}(?:[0-9a-f]{3})?$/i.test(str))` - otherwise, color codes like `#aba` won't match.

Comment: @SLaks: when I put your regex test (`/^#[0-9a-f]{3}[0-9a-f]{3}?$/i.test('#aba');`) into Chrome's Javascript console, it returns false. *EDIT:* it also returns false in Firefox's JS console.

Comment: The parentheses need to be escaped for the RGB regex to work properly: `/^rgb\s*\(\s*[012]?[0-9]{1,2}\s*,\s*[012]?[0-9]{1,2}\s*,\s*[012]?[0-9]{1,2}\s*\)$/i.test(str)`

Comment: `/^rgb\s*\(\s*([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|([01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\s*,\s*([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|([01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\s*,\s*([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|([01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))\s*\)$/i.test('rgb(255,29,3)')`

This handles rgb(0-255,0-255,0-255)

Answer (score 4):

You could create an abstract element and attempt to apply the color to that element:

```
function validate_color(c) {
    var litmus = 'red';
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.style.color=litmus;
    d.style.color=c;
    //Element's style.color will be reverted to litmus or set to '' if an invalid color is given
    if( c !== litmus && (d.style.color === litmus || d.style.color === '')){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed it to do, thanks! Quick question....I couldn't find much documentation for setting style.color.  While it seems to work correctly in all the browsers I tested, is this behavior stated anywhere in any official documentation (that you can't set style.color to an invalid value)?  Also, I noticed it doesn't mind if right parentheses are missing, for example "rgba(11,11,11" is valid.  Not that it's a problem, just wondering why that would be the case?

Answer (score 0):

**It's 2020 so I created a `npm` package for this:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-color

It validates HTML colors by `name`, `hex`, `rgb`, `rgba`, `hsl` or `hsla` values.

1. Validate *ALL possible HTML colors*:

```
   import validateColor from 'validate-color';
```

Usage:

```
   import React from 'react';
   import validateColor from 'validate-color';

   const ColorBox = props => {
     const {
       color = '',
       text = ''
     } = props;
     const theColor = color && validateColor(color) ? color : 'transparent';
     return (
       <div className="color-box" style={{backgroundColor: theColor}}>
         <p>{text}</p>
       </div>
     )
   };

   export default ColorBox;
```

2. Validate *only* HTML colors (`hex`, `rgb`, `rgba`, `hsl`, `hsla`), *without* `name`:

```
   import { validateHTMLColor } from 'validate-color';
```

3. Validate *only* color `hex`:

```
   import { validateHTMLColorHex } from 'validate-color';
```

4. Validate *only* color `name`:

```
   import { validateHTMLColorName } from 'validate-color';
```

There's a demo page as well, featuring the validation applied to a React component:

https://dreamyguy.github.io/validate-color/

From there you'll find the link to the GitHub repo. Plenty of tests were written, for good measure. I do accept pull-requests, long live open-source!